# How to call custom function?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm trying to create my first function. This is what I have so far:

```js
function subtracthour(str)  {
  var x = "04:30";
  var m = x.slice(3, 5);

  var h = x.slice(0, 2);
  if(h == '00') { h = "24" }
  var h = Number(h) - Number(1)
  if(h <= 9) {   
     h = "0" + h
   }

  var y = h + ":" + m

  alert(y);
}
```

This code works when I run it from a button just for testing.

What I would like to do is edit the function so I can use it like this:

```
c = "18:00" ;
c = subtracthour(c);
// c == "17:00"
```

How can I re-write it so that the function works like that?

Comment: what is an issue actually?

Comment: what is input of SubtractHour();

Comment: Did you mean `return y`?

Comment: first you forget semicolon in every line

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]. No one can tell what you want this function to do.

Comment: @Dipakchavda, semi-colons on _every_ line would generate errors.

Comment: Wow thanks for all the answer , Ill update my question , gimme a few sec

Comment: Sorry for confusing post , I hope my updated #1 give a better understanding of what im trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning your *original input string* as an output when you use `return str`, you need to return your output `y` instead:

```js
function subtracthour(str) {
  var m = str.slice(3, 5);
  var h = str.slice(0, 2);

  if (h == '00') { h = "24"; }
  var h = Number(h) - Number(1);
  if (h <= 9) { h = "0" + h; }

  var y = h + ":" + m;
  return y;    // Note this was return str
}

console.log(subtracthour("13:13"));
```

Alternatively, you could convert your timestamp to a `Date` and subtract an hour:

```js
function subtracthour(str) {
  return new Date(new Date("02/01/1970 " + str) - 3600000).toTimeString().substring(0,5);
}

console.log(subtracthour("00:13"));
```

Comment: Although this no longer fits with the code that you've since updated the question to, your new code doesn't even use the `str` input, nor `return` a value

Comment: I think your suggestion is what I wanted

Comment: I did try my best to write the first post as best as I could but instantly got a lot of minus rep :(

Comment: @Frederik84 I'm afraid there isn't anything that I can do about your lost reputation but recommend that you take some more time writing your questions in future, specifically *make sure that you write what your code is meant to do, and what it is doing instead of that*

Comment: Yes i'll make sure to  keep that in mind . Im sure my questions will be better when my skill level increases  . But anyway thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Your latest edit was great info, thanks alot. I just ran this function trough 100 rows of data , and no problem , I´m quite happy :=)

Answer (score 0):

This was what I was after and I think its working like I wanted now:

```
function GetData()  {
  var x = "04:30";
  var x = subtracthour(x)

  alert(x);
}

function subtracthour(str) {
  var m = str.slice(3, 5);
  var h = str.slice(0, 2);
  if (h == '00') {
     h = "24"
  }
  var h = Number(h) - Number(1)
  if (h <= 9) {
    h = "0" + h
  }

  var y = h + ":" + m
  return y    // Note this was return str
}
```

**Big Thanks to Nick A**